# What do I call this type of list on ebay?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

My apologies in advance if I posted this in the wrong place...

OK. I'd like to add a similar hierarchical/selectable list of data to my website as can be found on ebay's "sell a new item page" here:

http://cgi5.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?NewListing

Note: you may need to be able to log into ebay to follow the link. Sorry

(I've tried to post a screenshot to illustrate the table for those who can't follow the above link, but as I'm a new user to StackOverflow I'm not allowed to post images until my Reputation > 10. Bummer)

If you can't follow the link above, goto ebay.com, login (if you have an account), click the SELL tab->SELL AN ITEM and then the BROWSE CATEGORIES LINK which will bring up the list in question.

Ebay uses their version to make sure a seller lists their auction item in the proper category and I could use something similar for completely unrelated purposes on my own website.

It works like this: upon page load, column 1 is populated with a list of possible category options and when the user selects one of those options, a new (the 2nd) column of sub options is then displayed to the right of the first. When an option from column 2 is selected, column 3's options are displayed and so forth until the user has drilled down into the categories and arrives on one which does not have any additional subcategories. Ultimate, a single category number is displayed in the lower right hand corner one the user reaches the end of the category line.

2 questions:

1. To help me research how it works, what type of list is it? (Assuming it is a list and not a menu ect.)
2. In order for me to make one for my site, will it require adding code in javascript or are there online generators to make such an animal?

I've inspected the page's source before asking the question, but being fairly new to html/php and not having dabbled in javascript yet, I drew a blank on how to learn more.

Knowing what to call this type of list will help me google to find out how to make something that looks and functions in a similar manner for my data which is currently in a mySQL table.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: [SO] is not the place for this sort of question, which is why I've voted to close this as off-topic. It may be appropriate for [ux.se]. I've flagged the question so that a moderator can take a look at it and migrate it if they deem it appropriate to do so.

Comment: You're looking for [linked select boxes](http://johnwbartlett.com/cf_tipsntricks/index.cfm?TopicID=86).

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in HTML and its called 'selection list' with this code:

```
<select name="items" size="3">
<option value="ball">Ball</option>
<option value="toy">Toys</option>
<option value="something">Something</option>
</select>
```

You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5EXmc/

Of course you are going to need some javascript to understand which item was selected.

If you are interested in the javascript for this to displace what you selected:
http://jsfiddle.net/5EXmc/1/

```
$("select").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $("div").text(str);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you took 10 seconds to look at the HTML you'd learn that it's just a `select` element with a `size` property. This is just another mode of the input element.

Comment: "I've inspected the page's source before asking the question, but being fairly new to html/php and not having dabbled in javascript yet, I drew a blank on how to learn more."

Comment: I don't know how else to explain this .. it's right there on the page. You click it, it tells you `<select id="fcat" name="fcat" size="13">` what more can there be?